# getAttribute of element with the state (.active)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having trouble checking **the active state of an element attribute**. I tried below but it returned false even though the element has the attribute in an active state - (`.c-banner.active` is present)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const bannerElm = document.getElementById("banner");
    const isActive = bannerElm && bannerElm.getAttribute("class")
      .indexOf("c-banner.active") !== -1;  // returned false
}
```

Comment: So what is the value of `bannerElm.getAttribute("class")` ?

Comment: `.getAttribute("class")` is going to return the class attribute exactly as the value you see in the DOM, so why are you looking for `c-banner.active` with a period and no space like a css selector?

Comment: it returned "c-banner". and yes @BenSewards, you are right it returned the value exactly as is. However, the attribute attached is .c-banner.active so my question is how do I verify if the .active state css styling was applied. Thnx.

Comment: I am seeing a lot of answers on how to properly access the class/classList. The value of the class attribute when checked in the ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook is allegedly `c-banner`. Maybe the element is not in the expected state because of an operation that's asynchronous in nature? How do you set the active state of the banner? can you try to get the element class after a timeout? (just for debugging purposes)

Comment: @JanWendland setTimeout in combine with classList.contains worked for me!! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classList.contains` method to check if the element has the active class.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const isActive = bannerElm &&
                         bannerElm.classList.contains('c-banner') &&
                         bannerElm.classList.contains('active');
    }, 1000);
}
```

[UPDATED] wrap it within setTimeout() and it worked! In case anyone else is stuck with the component initialization orders issue that I had previously.

Comment: @user11151040 had you to it :)

Comment: @benshabatnoam yes, but all in all it contains labor :)

Answer (score 3):

Why you not use **classList** and **contains**?

`classList`.`contains();`

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const bannerElm = document.getElementById("banner");
    const isActive = bannerElm && bannerElm.classList.contains('c-banner') && bannerElm.classList.contains('active');
}
```

Comment: @user11151040 The code sample you had was incorrect. It should be .classList.contains(). Even though you were faster, but I am choosing the other answer. Just FYI, you can always click "edit" and re-validate the answer.

Comment: @displayname yes you are right. After mentioning the explanation, I forgot how to add it to the content this is very funny :) Now edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what's the best way of actually accessing the value of the class attribute, judging by your comments the issue appears to be of asynchronous nature.
To avoid using a hackish `setTimeout` solution, I would recommend to apply a mutation observer and react to changes of the attribute accordingly.
Here's one way on how to do it.

PS: Edited the answer to make it more suitable for what you're trying to achieve. In the end this won't make a huge difference other than that in case the banner state is changed before the debounce time runs out, the subject emits right away and you potentially save some time waiting as compared to using `setTimeout`

```
bannerIsActive$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const banner = document.getElementById('banner');

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
        const mutation = mutations[0];
        const classList: DOMTokenList = mutation.target['classList'];
        this.bannerIsActive$.next(mutation.attributeName === 'class' && classList.contains('active'));
    });

    observer.observe(banner, {
        attributes: true
    });

    this.bannerIsActive$.pipe(
         debounce(isActive => timer(isActive ? 0 : 1000)),
         take(1)
    ).subscribe(isActive => {
       // do something with the banner state
    });
}
```

Comment: @janwedland nice one! QQ. What if I only want to get the state once and ignore the state change? I thought of subscribe and onsubscribe, but perhaps there is a better solution!

Comment: I'd say it depends on what you're trying to do with the state. Are you using the state in your component template? In that case you could simply initialize it with false on your component and have the mutation listener callback update it in case the banner is set active.

Comment: If the scenario is a little more complex and you wanna i.e. make some sort of request based on the banner state, you could create a BehaviourSubject on your component, intialize it with false, subscribe to it with a debounce time of whatever you seem reasonable for the async operation to catch up and call the next method of the subject rom the mutation observer. You can then subscribe to it and no matter if the banner state change or not, you will get the current state of the banner after the debounce time. But maybe you can elborate more on what you're trying to achieve? @displayname

Comment: @displayname Edited that approach into my answer.

Comment: I tried it but it did not capture the active state.

Answer (score 0):

you should work with ViewChild rather then Access your DOM directly.
both will work, but this is the strict way to do it.

```
@ViewChild('banner') input; 
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var classAttributes= this.input.nativeElement.getAttribute('class');
    var result=classAttributes&&classAttributes('c-banner')
}
```